# Wordpress pages won't load after hosting transfer

Tags: wordpress

I've just transfered a wordpress website to another domain.
For the transfer I've made the following steps:

- Copied db and changed domainnames (http://olddomain.com to http://newdomain.com)
- Imported db on new host (via phpMyadmin)
- Changed wp-config to match new db settings
- uploaded all wp files

So the homepage works, but I can't visit the other pages. However, they are showing up in my admin page.

Comment: Did you check your .htaccess file ? And be careful when you change domain name in serialized data (you cannot simply replace strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past and have worked for me:

```
1- Export db from phpMyAdmin, then replace in the .sql file all references to old domain.
2- Imported db on new host (via phpMyadmin)
3- Changed wp-config to match new db settings
4- Uploaded all wp files
5- Regenerate .htaccess file, if you are using permalinks. 
   (you can do this the way @Riboflavin suggests)
```

Also, here you can find some additional information that could help:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 2):

If you are using permalinks you will need to regenrate them after the transfer. Go to `Settings → Permalinks` in your admin panel and choose the permalink option you would like to use and click `Save Changes`. This will regenerate the permalink portion of your .htaccess file for your new domain.

Answer (score 1):

Are the links to those other pages still pointing to the old domain?

If so, you could try the [Velvet Blues Update URLs plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) to update all the links in your site.

I've used this successfully in the past, but recommend that you back up your data fully before trying it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest transfer from my experience is through cpanel using fantastico or something that installs wordpress quickly. The process is as following:

1. Install wordpress on new hosting through fantastico or similar app
2. Delete everything in installed directory except for wp-config
3. Copy everything from old wordpress data, except for wp-config
4. Paste/transfer all that data to the new host
5. Now export old database and delete tables on the new one then import from old db
6. Change site URL within database to new one

   ---

Using fantastico helps in setting up databases quickly and wp-config. No need to do it manually and waste time. Just make sure to leave the installed one and not transfer the old one.

The whole process takes me like 2-3 minutes, I think its the fastest once you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to adjust your new .htaccess by regenerating it 
go to WordPress dashboard

> Settings > permalinks

then save modifications

if it's work then well done else you need to manually change it :
you will find the `.htaccess` content after saving modification in permalinks page copy the contents and create the `.htaccess` file in the root directory